# Gitkraken pull failed - rmdir error

Tags: git, gitkraken

I encountered an error when I commit an image, the process is already open in an other program (like ADOBE Photoshop) and I can't commit and the images are removed.

[image]

how can I fix it? Thank for your help.

Comment: What exactly did you do? You committed the image and then tried to `pull`? Which pull operation did you try (fast forward if possible, fast forward only, rebase)? Do you have other unstaged changes? What other processes are running? Did you try to close all other running programs?

Comment: I did a commit when images are already open in photoshop. It's works when photoshop is closed, but why can I commit my code without problem even if the program is open but not images ?

Comment: When you commit, you add things to your repository. This is no problem. Now you pull - i.e. you include remote changes into your repository. If there are changes locally as well as on your remote, some kind of merge is performed. This seems to try to delete the `/images` folder (I suppose because it does not exist in the remote repository). This deletion is what fails, because the images are still open in photoshop.

Answer (score 3):

You have to stop any process that is inside that folder, if you are using Visual Studio code make sure to disable git, which is enabled by default, or just close Visual studio code, it could be an open terminal as well

```
"git.enabled": false
```

Comment: Why is that required? The directory should not be removed anyway, since it is present on both branches.

Comment: closing VS Code fixed it for me

Comment: restarting the pc fixed for me.

Answer (score 2):

A fix that worked for me was using WSL (I'm sure git terminal will work too). Then run `git checkout <branch>` then `git pull`